# Setting heroku credentials for an app ON heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

I am building a heroku app which deploys heroku apps for my company.

I am using libraries such as gitpython and heroku3 to manage my application and everything works great on my local laptop.

However, when I launch it to heroku I am getting this error:

```
2017-05-03T16:31:43.368895+00:00 app[web.1]:   cmdline: git push --set-upstream heroku master
2017-05-03T16:31:43.368896+00:00 app[web.1]:   stderr: 'fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': No such device or address'
```

Basically, this error is saying that my app's heroku credentials are not initialized properly.

*(I performed `heroku auth:logout` on my local computer and rerun my script: I was indeed prompted with username and password on the terminal.)*

## How can I add my heroku's credential to my git client **if my git client is not my terminal?** Is there some `git config` I can run to set the heroku username and password for my git client managed by gitpython?

===

I know `~/.netrc` file is generated after running `heroku auth:login` on my local computer. However, I don't know where to place this file if my application is running on heroku.

Comment: Are you using Github?

Comment: No. I have opted to use .netrc file for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the URL of `https://git.heroku.com` is not correct.  When you created the app you should have a URLS of `https://example.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/example.git`. The later being the one you push to.  Have you run `git init` from within your root dir?

Also lots of good info on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps) for this.